# How to get the data by particular order from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have one mysql database table with a column like **favorite** having values 1,0,0,1,0,0,1. how to get the table data with favorite =1 first after that favorite=0, please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `ORDER BY favorite DESC` in the `SELECT` statement

Have a look at [3.3.4.4. Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query :

```
SELECT favorite FROM tbl_name ORDER BY favorite DESC;
```

Comment: Note for those reading- DESC stands for 'descending', meaning that the first returned value is the one where that column is the highest while the last is the lowest. Multiple ORDER BY statements can be used consecutively in a layered fashion (For example, sort by favorite, and where favorite is the same, sort by name).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY ColumnName ASC/DESC
```

You can refer this link. It'll be very useful.

http://thetricky.net/mySQL/GROUP%20BY%20vs%20ORDER%20BY

Thanks,
Hemang.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `<tablename>` order by favorite DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you have only two values 0 and 1 then you can use union all query as well

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE favorite = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE favorite = 0;
```